# Verificar data template

Tags: django, data, filtro, django-templates

Olá,

Pessoal como fazer uma comparação de data no template?

Tentei da seguinte forma

{% now "d/m/y" as data_atual %}

atual {{ data_atual }} - inicio         {{ t.data_inicio|date:"d/m/y" }}        -         {% if data_atual < data_inicio|date:"d/m/y" %}   true   {% endif %}

Resultado:
atual 23/02/22 - inicio 01/03/22 -
atual 23/02/22 - inicio 24/02/22 - true
atual 23/02/22 - inicio 23/02/22 -
atual 23/02/22 - inicio 22/02/22 -

Está comparando somente o dia ao invés da data completa

O que fiz de errado?

Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Consegui solucionar a questão definindo uma @property no model.

Assim fazendo a verificação direta e no template chamando a property como um campo normal no for.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).